# Implicit conversion from ICollection<T> to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core

`ICollection<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>` and something like this is valid:

```
ICollection<Computer> Computers {get; set;}
IEnumerable<Computer> Retrieve() => Computers;
```

But why does the compiler state that implicit conversion is not possible in the following scenario?

```
ICollection<Computer> Computers {get; set;}

// Error below
// Cannot implicitly convert from Task<ICollection<Computer>> to Task<IEnumerable<Computer>>
Task<IEnumerable<Computer>> RetrieveAsync() => Task.FromResult(Computers);
```

In order for this to work, I need to call `Task.FromResult(Computers.AsEnumerable())`

The question is ... why? `ICollection<Computer>` is clearly a `IEnumerable<Computer>` as well and when it's not wrapped in a `Task` implicit conversion works absolutely fine, why would wrapping it in a `Task` change anything at all?

Comment: For the same reason a `List<Giraffe>` is not a `List<Animal>` even if `Giraffe` is an `Animal`. `Task`, being a class, doesn't offer covariance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst `ICollection<Computer>` is an `IEnumerable<Computer>`, a `Task<ICollection<Computer>>` is not a `Task<IEnumerable<Computer>>`.

This is because for `Task<TResult>`, `TResult` is invariant.

[Covariance and Contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Answer (score 1):

Johnathan Barclay explained, why you get this error. If you want to solve it without calling `AsEnumerable()`, you can explicitely give the type parameter to the `FromResult` method in the `Task` class:

```
Task<IEnumerable<Computer>> RetrieveAsync() => Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Computer>>(Computers);
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0hEnfY